# problems installing scrapy ..missing gcc 4.0

Tags: gcc, scrapy

I am having trouble installing scrapy with easy_install, I get:

unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

I have gcc-4.2. I've been trying to downgrade to gcc-4.0 but cannot figure out a way ...

Comment: Which OS and which version of python?

Comment: I am using mac os 10.7 and Python 2.7.1

Comment: What does the full output show?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup your environment:

- First, install [Command Line Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-) (I'm not 100% sure that you can install without XCode, if not then install XCode from App Store).
- Then install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)

To complete macports setup run this command in Terminal.app:

```
% sudo port selfupdate
```

If you done, then you can install scapry from macports:

```
% sudo port install py27-scrapy
```

Afther this you should be able to use `scrapy` command in Terminal.app.